# how to implement break function in openmp nested for loop

Tags: c, openmp

I know that you can't set breaks on OpenMP for loop but could you suggest an alternative which will break from nested for loop. 
How can I stop all threads to work after some result is found?

the code is attached here

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) private( dict_len, success)
    {
        #pragma omp for collapse(5)
        for(int i=0; i<dict_len; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<dict_len; j++) {
                for(int k=0; k<dict_len; k++) {
                    for(int l=0; l<dict_len; l++) {
                        for(int m=0; m<dict_len; m++) {
                            unsigned char* result = X;

                            if (success == 1) {

                                    #pragma omp critical
                                    {
                                        printf("%s\n", result);
                                    }
                                     #pragma omp cancel for
                            }
                            free(result);
                            printf("unsuccessful!\n");
                            #pragma omp cancellation point for  
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but note the following points:

- `dict_len` must be equal to all OpenMP workers. Prefer using `firstprivate` or `shared` instead `private` to this variable.
- OpenMP does not activate for cancellation by default. You need to specify it setting the `OMP_CANCELLATION` environmental variable to true.

Comment: Could you suggest how to do that? `setenv("OMP_CANCELLATION", "true", 1);` is that a good way to do that?

Comment: I think it must be set before the program execution, because OpenMP checks for the variable at the beggining of execution. You can do it with `export OMP_CANCELLATION=true` command in sh and bash before you ivoke the program binary